# How to print output from both files matched on one column?

Tags: bash, awk

I have two files

```
 >vi cc4
163489921       ENSG00000145416
163490721       ENSG00000145416
163493030       ENSG00000145416
163494582       ENSG00000145416
163498263       ENSG00000145416
163506833       ENSG00000145416
163510223       ENSG00000145416
...

>vi bed_chr_4.bed
chr4    171975321       171975322       rs230   0       -
chr4    10204223        10204224        rs231   0       +
chr4    184363210       184363211       rs232   0       -
chr4    39547490        39547491        rs529   0       +
chr4    109740780       163489921       rs551   0       -
chr4    25929702        25929703        rs554   0       +
chr4    17624034        17624035        rs555   0       +
...
```

I would like to mach 1st column of cc4 and 3rd column of bed_chr_4.bed and print matched lines from bed_chr_4.bed plus matched 2nd column from cc4. The output that I want to get for this sample would be:

```
chr4    109740780       163489921       rs551   0       -     ENSG00000145416
```

I tried this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1;next}a[$3]{print $0}' cc4 bed_chr_4.bed >outfile
```

but I am getting only 6 column matches from bed_chr_4.bed and not the 2nd column from cc4, which is in this case: ENSG00000145416

I am getting only this:

```
chr4    109740780       163489921       rs551   0       -
```

Comment: Do you need to use awk or you could use other tools in your script (grep i.e.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. The problem is that you are assigning `$1` to `a[$1]`.
Please try instead:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} a[$3]{print $0 " " a[$3]}' cc4 bed_chr_4.bed > outfile
```

Precisely, it relies on the assumption that the 2nd field of cc4 holds a value
which is evaluated to be true. It may be safer to say:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;b[$1]=$2;next} a[$3] {print $0 " " b[$3]}' cc4 bed_chr_4.bed > outfile
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for clarification.